# MeteorJS: Template event is not trigger when in popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have this code. The problem is button viewcart click is not executed when click. Button viewcart is inside a popover. Any ideas how to trigger the event of button click viewcart?

*header.jade*

```
template(name="header")
  ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
    li
      button.btn.btn-info.cart(name="cart", type="button", data-container="body", data-toggle="popover", data-placement="buttom") Cart 
    #popover-content.hide
        +cart
```

*header.coffee*

```
Template.header.rendered = ->
  $('.cart').popover
    placement : 'bottom'
    html: true
    title: 'cart'
    content: ->
      $('#popover-content').html()
    return
```

*cart.jade*

```
template(name="cart") 
    table
        tr
         td
           button.viewcart  View Cart
```

*cart.coffee*

```
Template['cart'].events
  "click .viewcart": ->
      console.log 'im click!' 
      return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're are creating a new element with this `$('#popover-content').html()`, it wont be attached to blaze (don't know if this is the right way to put it). I faced the same issue with popovers on google maps. Where is the popover placed in the DOM?

EDIT: One thing you can do is instead of creating the template that way, just render it somewhere and make it appear whenever you need. You can see how they do it here https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-autoform-modals/ .